# Google Cloud Platform container list tags permission denied

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-iam, google-container-registry, google-cloud-deploy

When executing the command:

```
gcloud container images list-tags gcr.io/x/x
```

In the terminal, I get the following error:

> (gcloud.container.images.list-tags) Access denied: gcr.io/x/x

Which role do I need to give the user so that they are able to execute that command? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For read-only purposes (e.g. `list-tags`), `roles/storage.objectViewer` should (!?) be sufficient.

Google Container Registry (GCR) is slightly confusing because:

1. the API is [Docker Registry API](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/)
2. the backing storage is Google Cloud Storage (GCS).

As a result of:

1. there's no Google IAM roles specifically for GCR because there's no Google-specific API
2. the IAM role that's used is applicable to GCS.